# Flask web app: Google pie chart doesn't show in html output

Tags: python, flask, google-visualization

I would like to show statistics on the current database through a Google pie chart. However, the pie chart doesn't show on the html output even though you can see its related div element when you inspect the element.

This is the html file, the data comes from a dictionary linked to the database and I have checked that this data exists.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

            ['Domain', 'Number of artist in our database'],
            {% for k,v in dic.items() %}
                 [{{k|safe}},  {{v|safe}}],
                 {% endfor %}
             ]);
    var options = {
                width: 400,
      height: 240,
      title: 'Distribution of domains in our database',
      colors: ['#41E0A9', '#00B973', '#00AA5A', '#00AA5A', '#00CD8C']
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; margin-left:400px;margin-top:20px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Python flask function

```
 @app.route('/recruiter', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
 def recruiter():
  if session.get("email"):
    curl = mysql.connection.cursor()
    curl.execute("SELECT * FROM projects")
    data = curl.fetchall()
    curl.close()
    username = session.get("username")
    curl = mysql.connection.cursor()
    domain_dict = {}
    select_stmt = ("SELECT domain ,COUNT(*) FROM freelancers GROUP BY domain")
    curl.execute(select_stmt)
    tuples=curl.fetchall()
    dic = {}
    for i in range(len(tuples)):
      k = list(tuples[i].values())[0]
      v = list(tuples[i].values())[1]
      dic[k]=v

    curl.close()
    return render_template(
        "recruiter_2.html",
        projects=data,
        dic=dic)
 else:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

This is the output of the dictionary dic:

```
{'Graphic Design': 2, 'Illustrator': 2, 
 'Animator': 2, 'Digital Designer': 2, 
 'Photographer': 2, 'Filmmaker': 2}
```

It would be helpful if you can point out what mistake am I making in making the jinja reference. Also the pie chart works perfectly fine when I manually set numbers for each section. Is the Jinja2 loop wrong?

Thank you for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Not using the for loop solved the issue. Instead of initializing the data variable like so :

```
     var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

       ['Domain', 'Number of artist in our database'],
         {% for k,v in dic.items() %}
              [{{k|safe}},  {{v|safe}}],
              {% endfor %}
          ]);
```

Initialize it in this manner:

```
               var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

                ['Domain', 'Number of artist in our database'],
                ["Illustrator",  {{dic["Illustrator"]}}],
                ["Graphic Design",  {{dic["Graphic Design"]}}],
                ["Animator",  {{dic["Animator"]}}],
                ["Digital Designer",  {{dic["Digital Designer"]}}],
                ["Photographer",  {{dic["Photographer"]}}],
                ["Filmmaker",  {{dic["Filmmaker"]}}],

                 ]);
```